# Use Python in Azure Functions to download a File datatype file from Microsoft Dataverse/CDS

Tags: python, azure-functions, power-automate, common-data-service, dataverse

Microsoft recently introduced the ***File*** datatype for Power Apps Dataverse tables. I want to build a Power Apps Portals site that would utilise this datatype + Power Automate and **Azure Functions** to achieve file processing functionality. The processing would be as follows:

1. User on the Portals site uploads a File into the Dataverse table.
2. A Power Automate Flow that is looking for changes in the particular File column within the table is triggered.
3. The first step of the Flow is to retrieve the File's content using the action ***Download a file or an image***.
4. Pass the resulting object (which I believe is ***application/octet-stream***) into an Azure Function and **convert it (attempt) into a CSV file.** (File sizes could range from a fraction of a MB to 30+)
5. Run a bunch of Python code to validate it is indeed a CSV file + has xyz columns and rows + validation of datatypes etc.
6. The return value of the Function would be True/False.
7. Continue the rest of the Flow depending on whether True/False was returned.

I'm fairly confident I can get steps 1-3 and 5-7 done. I don't quite understand how to achieve step 4 -- many examples around the internet seem to regard Blob Storage, DotNet language, etc, but not this problem specifically.

Much appreciated all.

Comment: I think we can download file as stream then we upload the stream to azure function. At last azure function process the stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this python modules](https://pypi.org/project/pyDataverse/), export the data and upload file to azure blob storage by using [azure blob storage sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob?view=azure-python)(This is the [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#code-examples)).

After that, create a [blob trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python) to process the files in blob storage.

Comment: Aha, I fell into the same trap too... The link you provided goes to dataverse.org, which is not the same thing as Microsoft Dataverse. I will update my title to make this clearer.